# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 399920016 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 334MB until OOM

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have Project Android developed with java and xml when i run give me App has stopped and i get this error :
The error message you're seeing is an OutOfMemoryError, which occurs in Java when the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) runs out of memory. In this case, the error message indicates that there was an attempt to allocate 399,920,016 bytes of memory, but there were only 4,194,304 (4MB) free bytes left, and the total available memory was 343MB. This resulted in an "Out of Memory" situation

I try this in your manifest file:

```
> <application
> android:allowBackup="true"
> android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
> android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
> android:label="@string/app_name"
> android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
> android:largeHeap="true"
> android:supportsRtl="true"
> android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Stack trace

```
2023-10-17 18:11:00.682 7647-7647/ma.chutta.appnutrition E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ma.chutta.appnutrition, PID: 7647
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 399920016 byte allocation with 4194304 free     bytes and 334MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:858)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
```

How can i resolve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you requesting so much memory? Although that doesn’t seem like a lot. What device is it, and what are its constraints?

Comment: I used emulator Nexus 5 API 25 android studio but when i run application i have this error after login and pwd app has stopping

Comment: Apparently you load images from drawable resource and your images are much to big or you have too much images or you put bitmaps in a list or.... We do not know what you do only that you thank in advance.

Comment: so I don't know what can i do to work this app thanks in advance

Comment: Is this bitmap specified in xml layout? If so - then you change it to load it in the code, and then while loading downsample it - you may use glide for it. See here for more info: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap. Also it would be easier if you have shown more code.

Comment: Perhaps you put a large bitmap in `res/drawable/` [instead of `res/drawable-nodpi/` or `res/drawable-anydpi/`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/12/21/nodpi-anydpi-wtf.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using **Memory Profiler** will make it easier to detect the relevant problem.

> The Memory Profiler is a component in the Android Profiler that helps
> you identify memory leaks and memory churn that can lead to stutter,
> freezes, and even app crashes. It shows a realtime graph of your app's
> memory use and lets you capture a heap dump, force garbage
> collections, and track memory allocations.

To open the Memory Profiler, follow these steps:

1. Click **View > Tool Windows > Profiler** (you can also click Profile  in the toolbar).
2. Select the device and app process you want to profile from the Android Profiler toolbar. If you've connected a device over USB but don't see it listed, ensure that you have enabled USB debugging.
3. Click anywhere in the MEMORY timeline to open the Memory Profiler.

[Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler?hl=en)

Comment: I used pofiler but i can't know which problem and how can i resolved ?